# UIAlertViewDelegate clickedButtonAtIndex: usefulness?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

The `UIAlertViewDelegate` protocol defines two methods, `alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:` and  `alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:`, which seem to me to be identical in usefulness.

Why is there a `clickedButtonAtIndex` and a `didDismissButtonWithIndex` when they both do the same thing?  I realize there is also a `willDismissButtonWithIndex` that happens before the alert view is dismissed, but is there any reason to use `clickedButtonAtIndex` instead of `didDismissButtonWithIndex`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I found a more useful difference between the two:

When showing a `UIAlertView`, and the device goes to sleep, `alertView:didDismissWithButtonAtIndex:` gets called, even though the alert view is not actually dismissed.  It is shown again once the device wakes up.  `alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:` is only called when the user clicks one of the buttons.

Answer (score 12):

The `alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:` is called when the user clicks a button on an alert view whereas the `alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:` is called after an alert view is dismissed from the screen. (See the [UIAlertViewDelegate Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/UIAlertViewDelegate/UIAlertViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIAlertViewDelegate/alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:).)

The difference is minimal but it allows you to do something before or after animation.

Comment: willDismissWithButtonIndex method looks completely identical to clickedButtonAtIndex: then...

Comment: Yes, but there is a little difference. One is call when the user has pushed a button (so the alert is always visible) and the other is call when the alert has disappeared.
So, for example, if you want make a transition between 2 views it's better to do this when the alert has closed in the "alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:".

Comment: But is there any reason to use clickedButtonAtIndex over willDismissWithButtonIndex (not didDismiss) or vice versa?

Comment: You can use this method for tracking the start and the end of the UIAlertView animation. But I don't have any use case for that in my mind for the moment...

Answer (score 1):

If the alert view disappears for any reason (including being covered by another UIAlertView, going to sleep, etc.), `didDismissWithButtonAtIndex:` is called. This can mean that the method can be called even without the user clicking on anything. This can lead to unexpected behaviour if you depend on this delegate callback to be called in response to the user actually clicking on a button. In this case `clickedButtonAtIndex:` is more useful.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't reproduce Ed's behaviour by locking my device with the alert view present on iOS 7.

However, the most important difference between `alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:`, `alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:` and `alertView:willDismissWithButtonIndex:` is that the first method (`clickedButtonAtIndex:`) is only called when the **user explicitly taps on a button** on your alert view (hence 'clicked').

Is it possible that an alert view is dismissed without clicking on a button? Yes, you could programmatically hide an alert view using the `UIAlertView` method `dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:animated:`.

So, if you need some behavior to be always triggered upon the dismissal of the alert view—whether it was triggered by the user tapping on a button or triggered programmatically—then using the `didDismissWithButtonIndex:` and `willDismissWithButtonIndex:` makes more sense.